# How to map complex XML element to Java class property using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, binding, jaxb

I need to map my XML snippet onto Java class using JAXB, but have a tricky case. I have the following XML:

```
<person>
  <name part="first">Richard</name>
  <name part="last">Brooks</name>
</person>
```

and need to map it onto the following class

```
public class Person {

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
}
```

Could you please help me to figure out JAXB annotations to make it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), see [@XmlPath](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/XPath).

```
@XmlPath("name[@part='first']/text()")
private String firstName;

@XmlPath("name[@part='last']/text()")
private String lastName;
```

Related questions:

- [Using @XmlPath with jaxb/MOXy to map complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466534/using-xmlpath-with-jaxb-moxy-to-map-complex-type)

Comment: No, not yet, but isn't it something you could start with? Probably text() is missing in the XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach you could take, but would require you to create a separate class for Name:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
    @XmlElement(name="name")
    private List<Name> names;
    ...
}

public class Name {
   @XmlAttribute
   private String part; //would be set to "first" or "last"

   @XmlValue
   private String nameValue;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Again, not exactly what the OP wants.