# Parse particular fields from XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am working on a project where I need to parse an XML file using JAXB. Below is the sample XML:

```
<FirstLevel>
    <Second>
        <Third>
            <ProductName>Computer</ProductName>
        </Third>
    </Second>
    <Second>
        <Third>
            <ProductName>Mobile</ProductName>
        </Third>
    </Second>
</FirstLevel>
```

I only need the product names. In order to get that I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="FirstLevel")
public class DTOClass {

    private String productName;

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="ProductName")
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

}
```

But this works:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="FirstLevel")
public class DTOClass {

    private List<Second> second;

    public List<Second> getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="Second")
    public void setSecond(List<Second> second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    static class Second{

        private Third third;

        public Third getThird() {
            return third;
        }
        @XmlElement(name="Third")
        public void setThird(Third third) {
            this.third = third;
        }

        static class Third{
            private String productName;

            public String getProductName() {
                return productName;
            }

            @XmlElement(name="ProductName")
            public void setProductName(String productName) {
                this.productName = productName;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My questions are

- Do I need to create the inner classes(or classes) for each level of
  the XML to parse the XML(like the second one)?
- Is it possible to have only certain fields in java class which are
  needed(like the first one)?

Comment: As far as I know, you have 2 options: 1. create classes and properly map your xml (or inner classes as is in your code). 2. use xmlPath, you will need to tweak jaxb configuration a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466534/using-xmlpath-with-jaxb-moxy-to-map-complex-type/17466836#17466836

Comment: @CrazySabbath - Thanks. It really helped.